# show element only in this form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML form:

```
<div class="question">
    <td class="status1">
        <form action="update.php" method="post" id="form-id"  
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="recstatus">$row[12]</div>
        <input type="hidden" value=$row[1] name="audit_name">
        <select name="status">
            <option value="1">OK</option>
            <option value="2">Normal</option>
            <option value="3">Bad></option>
            <option selected="selected">Choose</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="subquestion">
    <label>Upload File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</div>
```

JS goes like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".question").each(function () {
        $(".subquestion").hide();
        $('select[name=status]').click(function () {
            if (this.value == "1" || this.value == "2" || this.value == "3") {
                $(".subquestion").show();
            }
            else {
                $(".subquestion").hide();
            }
        })
    })
});
```

If user choses one of this values it will appear another form item to upload file but the problem is that it appears in every form where class="subquestion" (p.s i have this form in cycle) I want to appear file upload input in  exactly  the same form where user choses value

Comment: You should probably decide on what you have. There are TD elements inside a DIV, a form that is never closed etc. This is all invalid markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first keep "subquestion"class div inside "question" class div

```
<div class="question">
....
<div class="subquestion">
    <label>Upload File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</div>
</div>
```

that should work and make sure that html tags are properly closed

use $( "div.question" ).next( "div.subquestion" )

i mean $(this).next(".subquestion").show();

Comment: hmm.. i want closest div with class subquestion and then display it